# Fedor's lazy load trouble

Tags: android

I use Fedor's lazy load for gallery show several pictures with URL.
The code

```
class BitmapDisplayer implements Runnable {

    Bitmap bitmap;
    PhotoToLoad photoToLoad;

    public BitmapDisplayer(Bitmap b, PhotoToLoad p) {
        bitmap = b;
        photoToLoad = p;
    }

    public void run() {
        if (imageViewReused(photoToLoad)) {
            System.out.println("imageViewReused");
            return;
        }
        // exist in memory cache or SD cache
        if (bitmap != null) {
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
        // cache not exist and loading
        else {
            photoToLoad.imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.load);
            photoToLoad.imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.FIT_CENTER);
        }
    }
}
```

It check the cache weather exist. 
If not, means loading not finish and show R.drawable.load.
But while the picture loading finish, the imageView does not update the image, and still show the drawable.
How should I modify to update while loading finish?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to call `notifyDataSetChanged()` after setting bitmap in case you are using `BaseAdapter` or its child in your gallery.